# Is it possible to save yanked history in numbered register? (without plugin)

Tags: vim

In Vim, as far as I know, the numbered register saves only the deleted history.

Is it possible to make it save also the yanked one?
(without plugin)

Thanks

Comment: The last yanked text goes into the register 0 (zero) by default. So it's "numbered".

Comment: Yes, I mean if I can register the last 10 yank, instead of only the last one. On my vim only the deleted goes in the numbered, not the yanked.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to make it save also the yanked one?

In fact, the registers 2-9 are rarely useful, as we can save all the important pieces into "letter" registers as needed. And there's "undo" for anything lost anyway.

> without plugin

Plugin is just a piece of code. You can do without a plugin, but you can't do without code.

```
" Shift previously yanked text through the numbered registers 0, 2-9
" note:
"   the register 1 is reserved for deletion
"   there's no "small yank" register
"   can break :h redo-register
"   $-blocks are broken
nnoremap <silent>y :set opfunc=YankeeDoodle<CR>g@
nnoremap <silent>Y :k] \| k[ \| call YankeeDoodle("line")<CR>
nnoremap <silent>yy :k] \| k[ \| call YankeeDoodle("line")<CR>
vnoremap <silent>y :<C-U>call YankeeDoodle(visualmode())<CR>
vnoremap <silent>Y :<C-U>call YankeeDoodle("V")<CR>

let s:ydict = #{char: "v", line: "V", block: "\<C-V>"}

function! YankeeDoodle(type)
    if has_key(s:ydict, a:type)
        let l:type = s:ydict[a:type]
        let l:mark = ['[', ']']
    else
        let l:type = a:type
        let l:mark = ['<', '>']
    endif
    if v:register is '"'
        for l:regno in range(8, 2, -1)
            call setreg(l:regno + 1, getreg(l:regno), getregtype(l:regno))
        endfor
        call setreg(2, getreg(0), getregtype(0))
    endif
    " go to start mark; register override; yank; forced-motion; move to end mark
    call execute(printf('normal! g`%s"%sy%sg`%s', l:mark[0], v:register, l:type, l:mark[1]), '')
endfunction
```

UPD. As @PeterRincker suggests we can use `TextYankPost` instead. The following code must be more robust, but still not 100%, as we must keep track of the register 0 manually (`TextYankPre` will be much better here, but, alas, we don't have it).

```
" note:
"   the register 1 is reserved for deletion
"   there's no "small yank" register
"   can break :h redo-register
"   still misses any manual register 0 change
augroup YankShift | au!
    let s:regzero = [getreg(0), getregtype(0)]
    autocmd TextYankPost * call <SID>yankshift(v:event)
augroup end

function! s:yankshift(event)
    if a:event.operator ==# 'y' && (empty(a:event.regname) || a:event.regname == '"')
        for l:regno in range(8, 2, -1)
            call setreg(l:regno + 1, getreg(l:regno), getregtype(l:regno))
        endfor
        call setreg(2, s:regzero[0], s:regzero[1])
        let s:regzero = [a:event.regcontents, a:event.regtype]
    elseif a:event.regname == '0'
        let s:regzero = [a:event.regcontents, a:event.regtype]
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: I think it was useful for me because I just want to have the history of all the yank. Like a normal clipboard manager. Sometime I need some yanked code that I didn't know when I was yanking. - Without plugin - so I can easily use it on any machine I am logged in. Thank you for the code. I will try it.

Comment: Maybe avoid mapping all the `yank` commands and use `TextYankPost` event instead. See `:h TextYankPost` for more information